# Python Multiprocessing (Flask) - Calling a function from main process

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing

This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, request, flash, Markup, make_response, Response
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

def getCookie():
    return request.cookies.get('username')

def worker(state):
    if state.value == 1:
        while True:
            print(getCookie())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processValues = Value('i', 1)
    p = Process(target=worker, args=(processValues, ))
    p.start()
    app.run()
    p.join()
```

So `worker` is the function started by Multiprocessing and it's trying to call function `getCookie()` which uses a function by `Flask`.

It seems to throw me an error saying

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

Anyway I can fix this?

**UPDATE**

Also, Ive tried sending the request function in the args like so

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, request, flash, Markup, make_response, Response
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

def worker(state, req):
    if state.value == 1:
        while True:
            print(req.cookies.get('username'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processValues = Value('i', 1)
    p = Process(target=worker, args=(processValues, request ))
    p.start()
    app.run()
    p.join()
```

And this just throws me another error.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to only read this cookie then you could send it as argument

```
p = Process(target=worker, args=(processValues, getCookie()))
```

or directly

```
p = Process(target=worker, args=(processValues, request.cookies.get('username'))
```

But you have to get it in worker as

```
def worker(state, username):
```

---

Similar way you could try to send full `request`

```
p = Process(target=worker, args=(processValues, request))
```

BTW: as I know `multiprocessing` uses `pickle` to send arguments as file.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply! Unfortunately i tried the last method u provided and it doesn't work :/. I've updated my question to show the code i tried. Am I suppose to do it like that?

Comment: add new error in question - maybe problem is in `pickle`. But if sending `request.cookies.get('username')` works then at least this way you can work.

Comment: But what i'm trying to do is. As my flask is running, I want a process in the background that constantly checks for the cookies. So i need to perform this `request.cookies.get('username')` quite a bit of times :(

Comment: but to get new value from `cookie` you will have to get new `request` from main process. Every process runs in differene memory and it has no access to current content in `request`. It gets only copy of current data. You would have to rather use `queue` to send it again and again.

Comment: Okay well thanks for all ur help :) I'll look into queue.